# Preventing editing of pages with certain IDs

Tags: wordpress

I have created this plugin to prevent certain posts being deleted.

This plugin removes the TRASH option from the page list.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'prevent_page_delete_activate' );
function prevent_page_delete_activate() {
    add_action('admin_menu', 'prevent_page_delete');
}

add_filter ('user_has_cap', 'prevent_default_theme_deletion', 10, 3);

function prevent_default_theme_deletion($allcaps, $caps, $args) {
  $ids = [2000,2333,4444];
  // trash will ve removed for this page IDs

  $numElementos = count($ids);

  for ($i=0; $i < $numElementos; $i++) {

    $post_id = $ids[$i];
    if ( isset( $args[0] ) && isset( $args[2] ) && $args[2] == $post_id && $args[0] == 'delete_post' ) {
      $allcaps[ $caps[0] ] = false;
    }

  }
  return $allcaps;

}
```

What would be the equivalent to remove the EDIT link from certain page ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your last comment, there is a few thing to consider:

- Visually hiding any hints to edit/delete ... etc.
- Removing any default link styling.
- Preventing direct access.
- Preventing database update.

You can intercept the post edit via the [`pre_post_update`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_post_update/) action hook which fires immediately before an existing post is updated in the database..

We can use [`post_row_actions`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_row_actions/) which filters the array of row action links on the Posts list table to prevent edits actions.

Finally we use the [`admin_head-{$hook_suffix}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_head-hook_suffix/) hook to remove any visual style and prevent the direct access through URL.

Everything is wrapped up in a single class to make it easier.

```
<?php

if ( ! class_exists( 'wpso70412723' ) ) {

    class wpso70412723 {

        public $protected_posts_IDs = [ //Define the protected posts IDs
            2000,
            2333,
            4444,
        ];

        public function __construct() {
            add_action( 'pre_post_update', array( $this, 'wpso_70412723_prevent_database_update_on_specific_post_edit' ), 10, 2 );
            add_filter( 'post_row_actions', array( $this, 'wpso_70412723_remove_edit_related_actions_from_post_action_row' ), 10, 2 );
            add_action( 'admin_head-edit.php', array( $this, 'wpso_70412723_prevent_link_style_and_click_ability_from_post_title' ));
            add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', array( $this, 'wpso_70412723_prevent_direct_access_to_a_specific_post_through_URL' ));
        } //public function __construct() {

        /**
         * Prevent specific posts edits actions.
         * Any post modifications (edit, delete, etc.) will be prevented.
         *
         * @param Integer $post_ID
         * @param Array $data
         */
        public function wpso_70412723_prevent_database_update_on_specific_post_edit($post_ID, $data) {
            if (in_array($post_ID, $this->protected_posts_IDs))
                wp_die('You are not allowed to edit this post.', 'Something went wrong...', [
                    'back_link' => true
                ]);
        } //public function wpso_70412723_prevent_database_update_on_specific_post_edit() {

        /**
         * Filters-out edit related actions from the array of row action links on the Posts list table.
         * 
         * @param String $actions An array of row action links.
         * @param Object (WP_Post) The post object.
         */
        public function wpso_70412723_remove_edit_related_actions_from_post_action_row($actions, $post) {
            if (in_array($post->ID, $this->protected_posts_IDs)) {
                unset( $actions['edit'] );
                unset( $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] );
                unset( $actions['trash'] );
            };
            return $actions;
        } //public function wpso_70412723_prevent_database_update_on_specific_post_edit() {

        /**
         * Prevent link style and click ability from the post title.
         * Fires in head section for a specific admin page.
         * In our case, the admin posts listing edit page.
         * 
         * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_head-hook_suffix/
         */
        public function wpso_70412723_prevent_link_style_and_click_ability_from_post_title() {
            if ( 'edit' !== get_current_screen()->base )
                return;

            global $wp_query;
            $posts = $wp_query->posts;
            foreach ($posts as $post) {
                if (in_array($post->ID, $this->protected_posts_IDs)) {
                    echo '<style type="text/css">
                        #the-list .post-' . $post->ID . ' strong a {
                            pointer-events: none;
                            color: initial;
                            text-decoration: none;
                        }
                    </style>';
                };
            };
        } //public function wpso_70412723_prevent_link_style_and_click_ability_from_post_title() {

        /**
         * Prevent direct access to a specific post through URL.
         * Fires in head section for a specific admin page.
         * In our case, the admin posts listing edit page.
         * 
         * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_head-hook_suffix/
         */
        public function wpso_70412723_prevent_direct_access_to_a_specific_post_through_URL() {
            if ( 'post' !== get_current_screen()->base )
                return;

            if (in_array(get_the_ID(), $this->protected_posts_IDs)) {
                wp_die('You are not allowed to edit this post.', 'Something went wrong...', [
                    'back_link' => true
                ]);
            };
        } //public function wpso_70412723_prevent_direct_access_to_a_specific_post_through_URL() {

    }; //class wpso70412723 {

    new wpso70412723();

}; //if ( ! class_exists( 'wpso70412723' ) ) {
```

> ### By the way, deleting a post is considered an edit.

You don't need your `prevent_default_theme_deletion()` function.

[image]

You could be tempted to use the `edit_post` action hook tho this wouldn't work because:

> `edit_post`: Fires once an existing post has been updated.

The "once" statement is why we need to use `pre_post_update`.

> `pre_post_update`: Fires immediately before an existing post is updated in the database.

Comment: Thanks but it is not working for me. Clicking on EDIT still allows the user to edit the banned posts. It would be nice to make the EDIT link vanish for those posts.

Comment: @Duck Indeed but that's not what you asked. They can click on the button and submit but the edit won't be registered. The database won't accept the edit. Do you want to prevent showing the edit button and page to the user too ?

Comment: yes, I would prefer not to show the edit button, like I did for the trash button on the code I have posted. Let the user edit it and save but not registering it on the database will appear to be a bug.

Comment: @Duck I've edited the answer, it should do what you described, let me know.

Comment: @JohnDoe I've edited the answer, it should do what you described, let me know.

Comment: thanks, sorry for the delay